# How to get min max date per row type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Scenario: A company has many branches in many states. A state may have more than one branch. Whenever an employee is transferred from one branch to another, an entry is made to a table like following

```
| EID |          DT | BRANCH | STATE |
|-----|-------------|--------|-------|
|   1 | 01-JAN-2000 |      A |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2001 |      B |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2002 |      C |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2003 |      D |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2004 |      E |    BB |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2005 |      F |    BB |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2006 |      G |    BB |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2007 |      H |    BB |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2008 |      A |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2009 |      B |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2010 |      C |    AA |
|   1 | 01-JAN-2011 |      D |    AA |
```

The requirement is to find out the duration for which a employee has been in a certain state. the output should be something like this

```
| STATE |         MIN |         MAX |    Duration |
|-------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|    AA | 01-JAN-2000 | 01-JAN-2003 |           3 |
|    BB | 01-JAN-2004 | 01-JAN-2007 |           3 |
|    AA | 01-JAN-2008 | 01-JAN-2011 |           3 |
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it in PL/SQL. The long way would be to use a for loop to traverse through each row and find the duration. But is there a way to do it in PLSQL without using loops?

here's a SQLFiddle <kbd>[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4442d/25)</kbd>

Comment: Is `Duration` the difference in years between dates, or something else?

Comment: yes, difference between min max in years. but if we can get min max, then finding the duration is not a biggy

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the approaches to get it done:

```
select max(z.state) as state
     , min(z.dt)    as min_date   /* main query */
     , max(z.dt)    as max_date
     , trunc((max(z.dt) - min(z.dt)) / 365) as duaration
  from (select q.eid
             , q.dt              /* query # 2*/
             , state 
             , sum(grp) over(order by q.dt) as grp
          from (select eid
                     , dt
                     , state     /* query # 1*/
                     , case
                         when state <> lag(state) over(order by dt)
                         then 1
                       end as grp 
                  from t1 ) q
       ) z
  group by z.grp
```

Result:

```
STATE MIN_DATE    MAX_DATE     DUARATION
----- ----------- ----------- ----------
AA    01-JAN-00   01-JAN-03            3
BB    01-JAN-04   01-JAN-07            3
AA    01-JAN-08   01-JAN-11            3
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4442d/39)

---

**Addendum #1**: Explanation of the query.

In order to get minimum and maximum date we simply have to apply `group by` clause, it's obvious, but we can't, because there is a logical difference between `AA` state before `BB` and one after `BB` state. So we have to do something to separate them, put them into different logical groups. And that's what inner-most (`/* query # 1*/`) and `/* query # 2*/` do.  The query #1 finds moments when state changes(compare current-row `state` with the previous one. `lag() over()` function is used to reference previous row in the data set), and  query #2 is forming a logical group by calculating running total of `grp` (`sum() over()` analytic function is responsible for that).

Query #1 gives us:

```
       EID DT           STATE        GRP
---------- -----------  -----    ----------
         1 01-JAN-2000   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2001   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2002   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2003   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2004   BB           1  --<-- moment when state changes
         1 01-JAN-2005   BB    
         1 01-JAN-2006   BB    
         1 01-JAN-2007   BB    
         1 01-JAN-2008   AA           1  --<-- moment when state changes
         1 01-JAN-2009   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2010   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2011   AA
```

Query #2 forms logical groups:

```
       EID DT           STATE        GRP
---------- -----------  -----    ----------
         1 01-JAN-2000   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2001   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2002   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2003   AA    
         1 01-JAN-2004   BB           1   
         1 01-JAN-2005   BB           1
         1 01-JAN-2006   BB           1
         1 01-JAN-2007   BB           1 
         1 01-JAN-2008   AA           2 
         1 01-JAN-2009   AA           2
         1 01-JAN-2010   AA           2
         1 01-JAN-2011   AA           2
```

Then, in main query, we are simply grouping by `GRP` to produce final output.

Comment: It seems to be working, but could you please explain what is actually going on here?

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4442d/86)

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT
    t1.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY dt )
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY state ORDER BY dt ) AS grp
  FROM t1
)
SELECT state,
       MIN( dt ) AS first_date,
       MAX( dt ) AS last_date,
       TRUNC( ( MAX( dt ) - MIN( dt ) ) / 365 ) AS duration
FROM   groups
GROUP BY state, grp
ORDER BY first_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4442d/86/0)**:

```
| STATE |                     FIRST_DATE |                      LAST_DATE | DURATION |
|-------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|----------|
|    AA | January, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2003 00:00:00+0000 |        3 |
|    BB | January, 01 2004 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2007 00:00:00+0000 |        3 |
|    AA | January, 01 2008 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |        3 |
```

As for how it works:

- The `groups` sub-query selects each row and allocates it to a group by subtracting the number of rows there have been of the row's `state` from the total number of rows of any `state` - the result is that:

  - Any sequential series of rows with the same state will have the same group number; and
  - For any given state, as the date increases then each group of rows will have an increasing group number (this does not necessarily apply when comparing groups of different states but this does not matter given the grouping used in the final bit).
- The final query then groups everything on `state` and `grp` and finds the `min`, `max` and `difference` for the dates within each group.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I changed the query and not it seems to work:

```
with t2 as
(select t1.*,
  case lag(state,1,state) over (order by dt)
  when state then 0 else 1 end as state_chng
from t1),
t3 as 
  (select t2.*,
    sum(state_chng) over (order by dt) as group_id
  from t2)
select distinct state,
  min(dt) over (partition by GROUP_ID) as min_dt,
  max(dt) over (partition by GROUP_ID) as max_dt
from t3
order by 2;

| STATE |                         MIN_DT |                         MAX_DT |
|-------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|    AA | January, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2003 00:00:00+0000 |
|    BB | January, 01 2004 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2008 00:00:00+0000 |
|    AA | January, 01 2009 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|    BB | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|    AA | January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2018 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: This is highly reliant on the branch data - it doesn't work if the employee joins a branch twice while in the same state. It also doesn't work when you have many groups of different sizes: [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d9cf/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Sans stored procedure, analytic functions are the only way to achieve this.

```
WITH s1 AS (
SELECT eid
     , dt
     , state 
     , CASE WHEN LAG(state) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY eid 
                           ORDER BY dt) 
                 = state           
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE dt 
       END mindt
     , CASE WHEN LEAD(state) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY eid 
                           ORDER BY dt) 
                 = state           
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE dt 
       END maxdt
  FROM t1
), s2 as (
select eid
     , state
     , MAX(mindt) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY eid 
              ORDER BY dt) 
       mindt
     , MAX(maxdt) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY eid 
                 ORDER BY dt) 
       maxdt
  FROM s1
)
SELECT eid
     , state
     , mindt
     , MAX(maxdt) maxdt
  FROM s2
 GROUP BY eid
     , state
     , mindt
 ORDER BY eid
     , mindt
```