# how to merge/group records based on difference in two column values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, group-by

I have following data set,

```
from            to           stayed
01.01.2011     03.04.2011    NY
03.04.2011     25.05.2011    NJ
25.05.2011     04.06.2011    NJ
04.06.2011     20.06.2011    NJ
20.06.2011     30.06.2011    NJ
30.06.2011     05.07.2011    CA
05.07.2011     20.07.2011    CA
20.07.2011     05.08.2011    NY
```

and have to be converted like,

```
from            to          stayed
01.01.2011     03.04.2011    NY
03.04.2011     30.06.2011    NJ
30.06.2011     20.07.2011    CA
20.07.2011     05.08.2011    NY
```

There is another data set with a gap from the previous "to" and the current "from" and that should be counted for a new row, as follows,

```
from            to           stayed
01.01.2011     03.04.2011    NY
03.04.2011     25.05.2011    NJ
25.05.2011     04.06.2011    NJ
04.06.2011     20.06.2011    NJ
20.06.2011     30.06.2011    NJ
30.06.2011     05.07.2011    CA
05.07.2011     20.07.2011    CA
20.07.2011     05.08.2011    NY
16.09.2011     20.09.2011    NY
20.09.2011     29.09.2011    NY
05.10.2011     20.10.2011    NY
```

and the expected result as follows,

```
  from            to          stayed
    01.01.2011     03.04.2011    NY
    03.04.2011     30.06.2011    NJ
    30.06.2011     20.07.2011    CA
    20.07.2011     05.08.2011    NY
    16.09.2011     29.09.2011    NY
    05.10.2011     20.10.2011    NY
```

to do such merging I have written complicated query with analytical functions. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your query as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get min max date per row type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299198/how-to-get-min-max-date-per-row-type)

Comment: I have added another data set with the difference in the gap between previous record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64692/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( "from", "to", "stayed" ) AS
          SELECT TO_DATE( '01.01.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '03.04.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '03.04.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '25.05.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '25.05.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '04.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '04.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '20.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '30.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '30.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '05.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'CA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '05.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'CA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '20.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '05.08.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "from" ) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY "stayed" ORDER BY "from" ) AS grp
  FROM   tbl t
)
SELECT MIN( "from" ) AS "from",
       MAX( "to" ) AS "to",
       "stayed"
FROM   groups
GROUP BY "stayed", grp
ORDER BY "from"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64692/7/0)**:

```
|                           FROM |                            TO | STAYED |
|--------------------------------|-------------------------------|--------|
| January, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |  April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
|   April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NJ |
|    June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     CA |
|    July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 | August, 05 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
```

**Edit:**

To answer your subsequent edit - here is one way of solving it:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef396/30)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( "from", "to", "stayed" ) AS
          SELECT TO_DATE( '01.01.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '03.04.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '03.04.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '25.05.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '25.05.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '04.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '04.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '20.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '30.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NJ' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '30.06.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '05.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'CA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '05.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'CA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '20.07.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '05.08.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '16.09.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.09.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '20.09.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '29.09.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '05.10.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), TO_DATE( '20.10.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ), 'NY' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH change_in_groups AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE WHEN t."from"   = LAG( t."to"     ) OVER ( ORDER BY "from" )
              AND  t."stayed" = LAG( t."stayed" ) OVER ( ORDER BY "from" )
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END AS has_changed_group
  FROM   tbl t
),
groups AS (
  SELECT "from",
         "to",
         "stayed"
         ,SUM( has_changed_group ) OVER ( ORDER BY "from" ) AS grp
  FROM   change_in_groups
)
SELECT MIN( "from" ) AS "from",
       MAX( "to" ) AS "to",
       MAX( "stayed" ) AS "stayed"
FROM   groups
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY "from"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef396/30/0)**:

```
|                             FROM |                               TO | STAYED |
|----------------------------------|----------------------------------|--------|
|   January, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
|     April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |      June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NJ |
|      June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |      July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     CA |
|      July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    August, 05 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
| September, 16 2011 00:00:00+0000 | September, 29 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
|   October, 05 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   October, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
```

An alternative solution using a hierarchical query:

**Query 3**:

```
WITH leaves AS (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT "from" AS "from",
         "to",
         "stayed",
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS leaf
  FROM   tbl t
  CONNECT BY PRIOR "stayed" = "stayed"
         AND PRIOR "to"     = "from"
)
SELECT MIN( "from" ) AS "from",
       "to",
       MIN( "stayed" ) AS "stayed"
FROM   leaves
WHERE  leaf = 1
GROUP BY "to"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef396/30/1)**:

```
|                             FROM |                               TO | STAYED |
|----------------------------------|----------------------------------|--------|
|     April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |      June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NJ |
|   January, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     April, 03 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
|      June, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000 |      July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     CA |
|      July, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |    August, 05 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
| September, 16 2011 00:00:00+0000 | September, 29 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
|   October, 05 2011 00:00:00+0000 |   October, 20 2011 00:00:00+0000 |     NY |
```

You probably want to profile the queries but from the explain plan the hierarchical query looks to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks so much and it works well. I didn't think about this row_number ;-)

Comment: Updated with two more queries - both of which will handle your new edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct 
   min(from) over (parttion by stayed order by from) as from_stayed,
   max(to) over (parttion by stayed order by to) as to_stayed,
   stayed
from table
```

Ok, try this corrected one

```
with t2 as
(select t1.*,
  case lag(stayed,1,stayed) over (order by dt)
  when stayed then 0 else 1 end as stayed_mod
from table),
t3 as 
  (select t2.*,
    sum(stayed_mod) over (order by from) as group_id
  from t2)
select distinct stayed,
  min(from) over (partition by GROUP_ID) as from_min,
  max(to) over (partition by GROUP_ID) as to_max
from t3
order by 2;
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed th doublicate entry for NY. Have a look here, it's a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299198/how-to-get-min-max-date-per-row-type/20299962#20299962